# Conditional dag run retry

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to change number of retry for a DAG dynamically ?

Imagine a simple dag:

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

def conditonnal_retry(value=True):
    if value:
        return "retry should occur if dag run fails"
    else:
        return "no need for a retry if dag run fails."

args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=15)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=['example']
)

run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='conditonnal_retry',
    python_callable=conditonnal_retry,
    dag=dag,
)

run_this
```

My goal is to have a function that check if it's worst it to attempt a retry or not and disable retry for this specific dag_run.
It could either mark the dag_run fails or success. I just want to avoid inefficient retry when some conditions are met.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also take a look at `ShortCircuitOperator` and use it to skip all downstream tasks. Some links:

- [ShortCircuitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.ShortCircuitOperator)
- [example_short_circuit_operator.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_short_circuit_operator.py)
- [The Zen of Python and Apache Airflow](https://xebia.com/blog/the-zen-of-python-apache-airflow/)

But before writing an implementation, please check some the drawbacks explained in this article: https://blog.diffractive.io/2018/08/07/replacement-shortcircuitoperator-for-airflow/.

Comment: Funny story, I've been looking for a way to do just what I say in the question and as this answer was great the first time, I now have a case where I couldn't use this solution. funny stuff sometime happen...

Answer (score 0):

This might useful.

you can update parameters anytime as per your requirement, but I suggest you should not do that because It might change the DAG behaviour and affect the running workflow.

if you still want to do that then **`Xcom`** will help.
http://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms

Comment: how does xcom could help in this case? it's made to share data between task not between dag. and xcom template will not help either as I need to change retry value after a python operator has run.

Comment: Ohh, I misunderstood then, but there's nothing can help you with your problem for now. @Kiwy